# Bootstrap input-group with two auto-width elements and one input filling remaining width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to make a 1-line `input-group` with icon (fixed width), then `select` (auto width, depends on the options) and then text `input` filling remaining width.

Here is the skeleton:

```
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">@</span>
  <select class="form-control">
    <option>Something</option>
    <option>Another</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
</div>
```

Here is the snippet: http://jsfiddle.net/qPdcs/722/

It doesn't work, because the input is displayed under the select.
I tried different approaches: played with widths, floats, table-cells, white-space, but nothing gives exact result what I need. Sorry if there is the same question, I couldn't find it.

Any ideas mates?

Answer (score 0):

**try this :**

```
<div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">@</span>
    <select class="form-control" style="width: 40%;">
        <option>Something</option>
        <option>Another</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
</div>

<style>
.input-group {
    display: flex;
}

.input-group-addon {
    width: 50px;
}
</style>
```

**have fun**

Comment: Sorry mate, that's not what I need. `select` must have `width: auto;`. With percentage width everything becomes very simple...